# Unexpected Ada Type Compatibility

Tags: ada, gnat

Why are Volts, Amps, and Ohms compatible?

```
with ada.text_io; use ada.text_io;
                                                                    
procedure main is                                                   
    type Volts is delta 1.0 / 2.0 ** 12 range -45_000.0 .. 45_000.0;
    type Amps is delta 1.0 / 2.0 ** 16 range -1_000.0 .. 1_000.0;   
    type Ohms is delta 0.125 range 0.0 .. 1.0E8;                    
                                                                    
    V : Volts := 1.0;                                               
    A : Amps := 1.0;                                                
    R1 : Ohms := 1.0;                                               
    R2 : Ohms := 1.0;                                               
                                                                   
begin                                             
                     
    v := A * (R1 + R2);
                       
    put_line(V'Img);   
                       
end main;
```

If the types the types are defined as `new Float` I get the following exception during compilation:

```
main.adb:22:12: error: invalid operand types for operator "*"
main.adb:22:12: error: left operand has type "Amps" defined at line 5
main.adb:22:12: error: right operand has type "Ohms" defined at line 6
```

I expected the use of type with Volts to define a new type that was incompatible with the other types as it wasn't an explicit subtype of the fixed point type.

Comment: The quantities in V = I . R suggests that Ampere * Ohm returns Volt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplication and division with operands of different fixed-point types is explicitly allowed (predefined) in the Ada standard since Ada 95 -- see http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-4-5-5.html, paragraph 18 -- but only in a context where the result is also expected to be of some fixed-point type (see paragraph 19.1/2). Addition and subtraction between different fixed-point types is not predefined, and of course different fixed-point types are not compatible in eg. parameters or assignment.

As to why * and / are allowed between different types, I don't have a clear answer. One of the relevant Ada Issues (http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ais/ai-00364.txt?rev=1.15) has this brief comment by Randy Brukardt: "... the Ada 95 rules came about because people complained about having to write a type conversion in:
A := B * 5.0;
which was felt to make Ada look bad.".

The same AI also has comments critical of the new rule... so opinions differ.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical representation for a fixed-point value is an integer; the represented value is the stored integer multiplied by the *small* for the type (for decimal fixed-point types, the *small* and the *delta* are the same; for ordinary fixed-point types, they may differ).

So for a type like

```
type FP is delta 0.001 digits 10;
```

the values 12.345 and 67.890 would be stored as 12_345 and 67_890, respectively. When you multiply them, you get 838_102_050, which represents 838.102_050, with a *small* of 0.000_001. So multiplying values of the same type yields a value of a different type. Something similar applies when the operands are of different types. The language therefore defines multiplication and division in terms of *universal_fixed*, though the result must be converted, explicitly or implicitly (as in your example), to a named type, as Holsti pointed out.

Similar issues arise with division; 67_890 / 12_345 yields 5, with a *small* of 1.0.

Another consequence of this is that you can multiply or divide a fixed-point value by an integer and get a value of the same fixed-point type without any adjustment: 3 * 12_345 = 37_035, which represents 37.035 = 3 * 12.345. Such multiplication and division operators for type `Integer` are defined by the language.

Comment: But why are the rules for fixed-point types different from those for others? Especially since we all make such a fuss about the benefits of strong typing when we’re selling Ada. (I should add that I’ve been known to make speed, distance etc all subtypes of float rather than trying to use separate types, so as to avoid a shedload of arithmetic operators, or conversions everywhere)

Comment: That's a good question, and one I don't know the answer to. The rules in Ada 83 were the same, except that the result always had to be explicitly converted. I wouldn't expect there to be an issue if these operations were only allowed for operands of the same type.